# Create a blob from a web stream in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipfs, node-streams

I am trying to pack a CAR file through `ipfs-car` (which uses web streams) and later send it in a request as a file but I'm not sure how to store it in a `Blob` after I have streamed in a `WritableStream`.

I have this piece of code

```js
import { CAREncoderStream, createDirectoryEncoderStream } from 'ipfs-car'
import { WritableStream } from 'node:stream/web'

export const packCAR = async (files) => {
  const blockStream = createDirectoryEncoderStream(files)
  const carEncoderStream = new CAREncoderStream([])
  const outStream = new WritableStream()
  await blockStream.pipeThrough(carEncoderStream).pipeTo(outStream)
  const blob = new Blob(/* what do I put here? */)
}
```

I haven't found anyone doing this, I only saw how to convert `Blob` to a stream, so help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the content of the WritableStream into a Blob. This can be done by transforming the WritableStream into a ReadableStream, then converting it into an ArrayBuffer, and finally storing the ArrayBuffer into a Blob.

```
import { CAREncoderStream, createDirectoryEncoderStream } from 'ipfs-car'
import { WritableStream, ReadableStream } from 'node:stream/web'

export const packCAR = async (files) => {
  const blockStream = createDirectoryEncoderStream(files)
  const carEncoderStream = new CAREncoderStream([])
  const chunks = []
  const outStream = new WritableStream({
    write(chunk) {
      chunks.push(chunk)
    },
    close() {
      console.log('Stream is closed.')
    }
  })
  await blockStream.pipeThrough(carEncoderStream).pipeTo(outStream)
  const arrayBuffer = await new Blob(chunks).arrayBuffer()
  const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer])
  return blob
}
```

Comment: This is supper helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new Response(readable).blob()` to convert a `ReadableStream` to a `Blob`, which allows simpler code:

```
import { CAREncoderStream, createDirectoryEncoderStream } from 'ipfs-car'
import { WritableStream, ReadableStream } from 'node:stream/web'

export const packCAR = async (files) => {
  const blockStream = createDirectoryEncoderStream(files)
  const carEncoderStream = new CAREncoderStream([])
  const readable = blockStream.pipeThrough(carEncoderStream)
  const blob = await new Response(readable).blob()
  return blob
}
```

Comment: that's a cool way of handling it! Unfortunately I'm locked in to Node 16 for now, and `Response` is stable only in 18, but good to know